# access to IApplicationBuilder using Bit Framework

Tags: asp.net, bit-framework

I am using bit framework in my project, I want to add UseHttpsRedirection as a middleware in appstartup.cs, how can i do this using bit framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use this code:

```
 dependencyManager.RegisterAspNetCoreMiddlewareUsing(aspNetCoreApp =>
            {
                AppEnvironment env = DefaultAppEnvironmentsProvider.Current.GetActiveAppEnvironment();
                if (!env.DebugMode)
                    aspNetCoreApp.UseHttpsRedirection();

            });
```